# Feynman-Wheeler absorber theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Firstly, I’m sorry if this is not a question that should be here. 
I would like to ask if anyone could link or guide me to where I could find resources (articles, books, etc.), about Feynman-wheeler absorber theory, more specifically about the advanced-retarded interactions, namely with photos (which still confuses me a lot) Feynman’s new approach to the self-interaction idea and if possible, some more resources regarding the existence of fields and hypothesis on how we can eliminate them entirely.

I understand that the internet is vast and has everything I’m looking for but I find it very hard to find specific and reputable resources when I’m not entirely sure what I should be searching for. 
Would appreciate some help.

Thank you

Edit: Quick background: I’m not a physicist, only an enthusiast and I’ve never understood fields, in the sense that I’ve always had the idea that it’s simply a construct to explain, using an abstraction level, why some interactions happen when there are no apparent direct interactions. I’m trying to search if anyone has been thinking this way or if I am simply misguided in thinking that all interactions must be direct, in one way or another.

Comment: you can try one of the original articles : https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.21.425

Comment: Oh thank you for that. I’m embarrassed to admit that I didn’t know you could find such articles for free and that easily.

Comment: Fields are not just an abstraction, you actually **see** light, which is a visible spectrum of electromagnetic field(s). You would not be able to "see an abstraction", hence it's not just an abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

You could try chapter five of Feynman's biography: *The beat of a different drum : the life and science of Richard Feynman* which goes into detail on how Feynman as a teenager fell in love with the idea of an electron not having a self-reaction, then developing the idea with Wheeler as a grad student. With an account, you can borrow the book for one hour [here](https://archive.org/details/beatofdifferentd0000mehr/mode/2up)

Nowadays the Feynman-Wheeler absorber theory isn't taken seriously as a competitor to QFT which models electrons in terms of a universal electron field, like the electromagnetic field for photons. For more on this as a lay-reader, I recommend watching *Quantum Fields: The Real Building Blocks of the Universe - with David Tong*

Answer (score 0):

The original articles by Feynman and Wheeler certainly need a lot of physics knowledge about action etc.
For an enthusiast, some of the comments on the theory in the Feynman lectures on physics vol. 1 may be easier to follow even though he does not go into the full amount of details. Also, he writes about it in "Surely you're joking Mr. Feynman", where he says that the theory cannot explain things such as the Lamb shift in QED.

PS: regarding your point about fields: in 4d two particles connected by a light line are actually touching according to the metric, so in some sense one does not need a field to convey an interaction. All in all the field concepts works nicely though and absorber theory makes a lot of things hard to think about. I still like it though.